# How to echo a value from select query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How do i get the value of id from the following query

```
$id = $this->db->query("SELECT id from tbl_profile_main WHERE token_='".$token."';");
```

Comment: Will it return only one row at a time or multiple rows can be returned ?

Comment: only one row at a time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$row = $id->row();
echo $row->id;
```

Answer (score 2):

To echo `id` from select query use `->row()`

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id from tbl_profile_main WHERE token_='".$token."'"); 

$id = $query->row();
echo $id->id;// will echo only id one time
```

Read https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $this->db->select('id')->where(array('token_'=>$token))->get('tbl_profile_main');

if($query->num_rows()>0{



//if multiple rows
 $result = $query->result_array();
  foreach($result as $id){

    echo $id['id'];

  }

   //if one row

    //  $id = $query->row();
   // echo $id->id;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id from tbl_profile_main WHERE token_='".$token."';");
$row = $query->row();

if (isset($row))
{
   echo $row->id;        
}
```

**For Multiples Result**

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id from tbl_profile_main WHERE token_='".$token."';");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   echo $row->id; // Echo id of all result and retun as object         
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If one row:

```
$id = $id->row_array()['id'];
```

if multiple rows:

```
foreach($id->result_array() as $ids) {
  print $ids['id']; // or save to an array or whatever you please
}
```